# unable to install cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore to cordova android platform

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins, jsonstore

I have downloaded the code from [here](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/JSONStoreCordova/tree/release80). Then from the command-line I navigated to the root folder of the project. Then I tried to add Android platform by running `cordova platform add android`. But I got the following error:

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore" for android
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android:
6.0.0, failed version requirement: >=5.1.1 <6
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore' for android
```

Do I have to install cordova-android earlier that 6.0.0? what if I want to work with the latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore does not support cordova-android@6.0. This is known and being handled by the MobileFirst Foundation team.

Please keep a look out for an upcoming MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 iFix that will update the cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore to support cordova-android@6.0.

At this time please use an earlier version of cordova-android.